# How do I correctly add a link in the html() method @ jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my current code that's working just fine:

```
$("h2").html("Well played!");
```

What if I wanted to link the words "Well played!" to a page of some sort?

I tried doing some different variations of

> < a href="">

...but that simply didn't work. Any help? :)

Comment: What happened when you tried it? The `<a>` snippet there of course is incomplete. Did you add a full and correct tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to append the link to the `h2` element:

```
$('h2').html('<a href="http://path.to.whatever/page.html">Well played</a>');
```

Or you could simply use:

```
$('h2').append('<a href="http://path.to.whatever/page.html">Well played</a>');
```

Or:

```
$('<a />', {'text' : 'well played', 'href' : 'http://path.to.whatever/page.html'}).appendTo('h2');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QrLTE/)

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: +1 for showing appendTo method example with html attributes as object notation :). seeing this first time

Comment: Thanks! It's not commonly used (so far as I've seen from examples used here on Stack Overflow), but I imagine that's because it doesn't seem well-known. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("h2").html("<a href='some.html'> Well Played </a>")
```

or with **[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)** method

```
 $("<a href='some.html'> Well Played </a>").appendTo($("h2"));
```

or with **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** method

```
 $("h2").append($("<a href='some.html'> Well Played </a>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
var link = $(document.createElement('a'));
link.attr({"href" : "http://www.test.com/link"}).text("Well Played!!");
$('h2').append(link);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E5Pnd/4/)

Hope that helps.